# import GitHub project into android studio JetBrains directed

Tags: flutter, android-studio, github

I want to import a flutter project from GitHub into android studio. I directed to the page with this:

```
Please continue only if this page is opened from a JetBrains IDE.
```

and ->`authorize in GitHub` ->then it shows me a popup menu -`username and password`

My Git hub username and password doesn't work here.
What is this for?
why do I directed to this?
How can I import a project?

android studio 2021
Here is the project:
https://github.com/londonappbrewery/magic-8-ball-flutter

[image: gh clone]

and I directed here

[image: credentials]

Answer (score 0):

> my Git hub username and password doesn't work here

Your password would not work indeed.
Try instead to use a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) as a password, and check if the popup disappear then.